# How to debug MIT-DLEP source?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, gdb

I want to debug the following source:

https://github.com/mit-ll/LL-DLEP

I already compiled with command:

`$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`

When I execute `gdb Dlep` gdb is saying no debug symbols are found.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the binary with debug symbols was deployed to `/usr/local/bin`.